# Graphics in Conway's Game of Life "MissingMemberException" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

```
Public Class GameOfLife
Dim grid(63, 63) As Boolean
Dim input(63, 63) As Boolean
Dim generations As Integer = 0
Dim change As Boolean = False

Sub GameOfLife_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To 63
        For j As Integer = 0 To 63
            grid(i, j) = False
        Next
    Next

    Dim g As Graphics = sender.Graphics
    g.Clear(Color.White)
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel
    Dim rect As Rectangle
    For i As Integer = 10 To 640 Step 10
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, i, 640, i)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, 0, i, 640)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To 63
        For j As Integer = 0 To 63
            If grid(i, j) Then
                rect = New Rectangle(i * 10, j * 10, 10, 10)
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

When I try to build this in Visual Studio, it throws "MissingMemberException" when trying to build `Dim g as Graphics = sender.Graphics` - Visual Studio 2015 is thinking `Graphics` is a class but it isn't. How do I bypass the exception?

Note: This isn't the only `Sub` in the code but I will provide the entirety of the code if need be.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `Object` does have a `Graphics` member

Comment: You need to do your drawing in the `Paint` event, not the `Load` event, and you want to use `PaintEventArgs.Graphics`, not `object.Graphics`.

Comment: `DataGridView` can be easy approach with row and columns size = 10

Comment: @Plutonix I've tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DourHighArch I'll try that

Comment: @Fabio I'll try that

Comment: It probably did exactly what it is supposed to do - keep code like that from compiling so that possible run time errors become compiler errors